# Information about CGAL and alternatives

Tags: embedded, 2d, linear-equation

I'm working on a problem that will eventually run in an embedded microcontroller (ESP8266). I need to perform some fairly simple operations on linear equations. I don't need much, but do need to be able work with points and linear equations to:

1. Define an equations for lines either from two known points, or one
   point and a gradient
2. Calculate a new x,y point on an equation line that is a specific distance from another point on that equation line
3. Drop a perpendicular onto an equation line from a point
4. Perform variations of cosine-rule calculations on points and triangle sides defined as equations

I've roughed up some code for this a while ago based on high school "y = mx + c" concepts, but it's flawed (it fails with infinities when lines are vertical), and currently in Scala. Since I suspect I'm reinventing a wheel that's not my primary goal, I'd like to use someone else's work for this!

I've come across CGAL, and it seems very likely it's capable of all this and more, but I have two questions about it (given that it seems to take ages to get enough understanding of this kind of huge library to actually be able to answer simple questions!)

1. It seems to assert some kind of mathematical perfection in it's calculations, but that's not important to me, and my system will be severely memory constrained. Does it use/offer memory efficient approximations?
2. Is it possible (and hopefully easy) to separate out just a limited subset of features, or am I going to find the entire library (or even a very large subset) heading into my memory limited machine?

And, I suppose the inevitable follow up: are there more suitable libraries I'm unaware of?

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

The problems that you are mentioning sound fairly simple indeed, so I'm wondering if you really need any library at all. Maybe if you post your original code we could help you fix it--your problem sounds like you need to redo a calculation avoiding a division by zero.

As for your point (2) about separating a limited number of features from CGAL, giving the size and the coding style of that project, from my experience that will be significantly more complicated (if at all possible) than fixing your own code.

In case you want to try a simpler library than CGAL, maybe you could try [Boost.Geometry](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/index.html)

Regards,